# How can I split this dictionary in a column in to their own columns?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dictionary, split

How can I make this dictionary in a column into its own columns? With the Keys being the column name and the value being the data

This is the dictionary, would like to have keys as the column title and values the data:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
dct = {'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'b', 'key3': 'c'}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[list(dct.values())], columns=list(dct.keys()))
```

[image]